# How to specify fork/remote when passing branch names? For example when trying to rebase between forks?

Tags: git, github, branch, rebase

I'm trying to rebase a branch from my coworker's fork onto the same branch in my fork, because he's made some bug changes and committed them to his fork's branch that I want to incorporate into my fork's branch before I continue working.

I think how you'd rebase from one branch to another (and both branches are on the same fork) is you'd checkout the fork that has the changes you want, then run `git rebase <base>`, where base is the name of the branch you're wanting to rebase onto.

I'm thinking that I could do the following:

Add my coworker's fork as a remote, run `git fetch <coworkerFork>` to get his version of the branch, checkout that branch, then finally run `git rebase <x>` where x is the name of my version of the branch on my fork.

Firstly, is it possible to do this?

If so, how do I specify my branch? Can I prefix the branch name with the fork name or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

If you call your coworker's remote `coworkerFork`, their branch `feature` will be called `coworkerFork/feature`.

Yes, what you describe is possible, and would go roughly as you say, but you're making your life harder than you need to. Consider instead cherry-picking the bug fixes, merging their branch into yours, or rebasing your branch onto theirs.

**Details**

When you fetch `coworkerFork`, you'll have branch `coworkerFork/feature` in your sandbox, and also `feature` as your own branch, and possibly `origin/feature` if that branch also exists on `origin`. Pretty much as you said in your question:

```
git remote add coworkerFork <URL>
git fetch coworkerFork
```

When you checkout `coworkerFork/feature`, you'll be in detached HEAD mode. You can make your life easier by giving it a local branch name. Then you can rebase that on your own `feature` branch.

```
git checkout coworkerFork/feature
git checkout -b coworker-feature
git rebase feature
```

And now you will need to bring your own feature branch to the result of this rebase:

```
git checkout feature
git merge coworker-feature
```

At this point, you don't need the `coworker-feature` branch anymore:

```
git branch -d coworker-feature
```

**Alternatives**

Although this procedure would work, I would recommend it. Besides being quite complicated, it will result in your coworker's commits all being *after* you own commit on that branch, and then your subsequent commits after theirs. If that's what you want, then OK, go ahead, but here are three much simpler solutions. All of these assume only the `git remote add` and `git fetch` commands above, and that you're currently on your own `feature` branch.

**Alternative 1: cherry pick**

Cherry-pick only the bug fixes you need instead of the whole branch:

```
git cherry-pick <sha1 of the bug fix commits you want>
```

this will also put your coworker's commits after yours, but it won't bring in all their work, only the bug fixes you need. Then when you do your PR, you won't bring in all their potentially unfinished changes, only your work in the bug fixes you needed.

**Alternative 2: merge their branch into yours**

If you expect your coworker to eventually PR the commits on `coworkerFork/feature` as is, the friendliest option might be to merge their branch into yours:

```
git merge coworkerFork/feature
```

This will create a bubble in the history that will leave a clear trace of what you did. I personally like that. Not everyone does.

**Alternative 3: rebase yours onto theirs**

If you want your coworker's commits before yours, so that your work ends up all together after their commits, rebase your branch onto theirs instead of the other way around. Again, while on your own `feature` branch, do:

```
git rebase coworkerFork/feature
```

Besides giving you a nicer linearity than rebasing their branch onto yours, it's also a lot simpler to do!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Apologies for the late response, and thank you very, very much. This helps immensely, and it helps with so much more than just my question. 

I've two questions if that's okay, but really your explanation is one of the most clear ones I've ever seen, and this is the first explanation I've seen where these various git concepts have actually started making sense to me.

Comment: Question 1: `git cherry-pick <sha1 of the bug fix commits you want>` 
Where does Git look for the sha1 of commits? Given an sha1, will it be able to find any commit in my coworker's branch so long as I've fetched that branch (is fetching the prerequisite requirement)?

Comment: Question 2: `git checkout -b coworker-feature`
Why is it that I'd get a detached HEAD when I checkout my worker's branch? Doesn't a detached HEAD only happen when you checkout a specific commit?

Comment: Question 1: once you've done the fetch, your coworker's branches exist inside your local sandbox. When you do `git log coworkerFork/feature` or cut and paste a sha1 from that log, you're doing strictly local operations. Only the `git fetch coworkerFork` needs to connect remotely, and it downloads everything you need to inspect their commits up to the moment you did the fetch.

Comment: Question 2: `coworkerFork/feature` is *not* a local branch, so you cannot be on that branch. When you have branch `origin/foo` and you do `git checkout foo`, you're not actually checking out branch `origin/foo`: instead, you're creating a local branch `foo` whose upstream branch will be `origin/foo`. When you explicitly say `git checkout remote/branch`, you bypass all that, and it's just like doing `git checkout <sha1 of remote branch>`.

Comment: You could have created a local branch whose upstream was `coworkerFork/feature`: `git branch --track coworker-feature coworkerFork/feature`, but I would not bother in your workflow: the reason you'd want it is to be able to push back to their fork, but you should not (and probably cannot) do that, you want to push to your own fork or wherever you normally push.